# Should players know the name of monsters when they are encountered?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounter-design, encounters, knowledge-check

This is a question that I frequently ask myself as a DM. I usually play a (home made) rule that you must first  succeed on an intelligence check with a DC that varies depending on the knowledge of the monster, this would mean if they encounter an Aboleth; an unknown monster to most, the DC would be higher than a Goblin.

Is how it should be or should the players know the names of encountered monsters?

Comment: I’ve added two duplicates here, between them, you should definitely have your answer.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov since [duplicate answer doesn't mean duplicate question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/27377), why this is closed as a duplicate? It asks specifically about monster names and the linked questions are about their own things. First one is specifically about new players and second one is about out-of-game knowledge vs character knowledge.

Comment: @enkryptor This one seems pretty obvious to me. If OP thinks neither of those questions answer this one, they can say so.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the answer might be the same. But this does not mean the question should be closed as a dup. At least, it was what you told me not very long time ago... (I don't want to sound aggressive, I'm just confused again now)

Comment: @enkryptor I closed this question because it has been asked before. I didn’t even read the answers to the other questions.

Comment: @enkryptor If the answer is the same, then the questions must be similar enough to be considered duplicates, even if they aren't perfectly identical.

Comment: @RevanantBacon this was exactly my point, see the relevant meta question https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11475/ which has the title "Does duplicate answers mean duplicate questions" in its first iteration